# dlsym() function returns wrong function address (in MIPS stubs section of other library)

Tags: c++, mips, embedded-linux, dynamic-linking, dlsym

I am developing shared library (.so) that can be loaded as plugin in another program. That program consists from set of other libraries. One of whose libraries, let it be called libA.so, exports own implementations ::operator new() and ::operator delete(). But I don't want to use this implementation of new and delete, and use own implementation (statically linked with my library). All works fine, but libA.so have function, that returns pointer to allocated memory and I should free it with calling operator delete from libA.so. So, I need address of _ZdlPv symbol from libA.so.

I am using function dlsym for obtain address of _ZdlPv: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "_ZdlPv"). My own implementation of operator delete (_ZdlPv symbol) is not present in dynamic symbols table, in my shared library, so I expecting to get address of operator delete() defined in libA.so.

But I got completely wrong result from dlsym function -- it returns address that resides inside in other library libB.so. And libB.so doesn't contains definition of _ZdlPv symbol, but it requires this symbol (it is undefined in that library). And address returned by dlsym() points to .MIPS.stubs section of libB.so. Looks like this is something like PLT (but on MIPS architecture -- yes, I am developing for MIPS). And when I am calling function with address returned by dlsym -- thread terminates. Hard to debug...

That is wrong here?  Why dlsym() not works for me?  As I know, $gp registers hold pointer to "global linkage table". Every shared library has own linkage table?  And calling function from stubs section, gp should have correct value -- right?  And when I am calling code from stubs section of other library (libB.so) -- I am calling it with incorrect $gp value, because of this thread crashes?

But why dlsym() returns pointer to code in stubs section of other (libB.so) library?  This is because stubs section of my library doesn't contain _ZdlPv symbol, because it not present in dynamic symbol table of my library?

If I am right in my assumptions, I not understood, how can I call arbitraty function from other library using dlsym() on MIPS platform?

Comment: If I substitute dlopen("libA.so",RTLD_NOLOAD|RTLD_LAZY) instead of RTDL_DEFAULT -- all works correctly.

But dlopen(NULL, 0) not works (gives wrong address).

Comment: It seems that this function was buggy in the past. Maybe check for an update. http://linux-mips.linux-mips.narkive.com/L9nsurqu/problems-with-dlsym-on-mips-looking-for-advice